# Dropdown menu on click change

Tags: plugins, menus, javascript, dropdown

Im working on a website where I need to create a submenu that shows only the parent pages.
When I click on one of the parents it has to show the children from that parent.

Here is the menu hierarchy I used this widget plugin: Subpages Extended for showing the parents and children:

- Parent
  - Parent1 from parent
    - Child1 from parent1
    - Child2 from parent1
  - Parent2 from parent
    - Child1 from parent2
    - Child2 from parent2

Could you explain me or give an example/tutorial on how to do it?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have to use any plugin for that, check out:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

and use `$depth` to control the levels you want to display.